# automatic rolling update with updated GCR image Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I create kubernetes services and deployments via `kubectl create -R -f ./kubernetes`

I use Google Cloud Builder to build docker image and push to GCR repository

Here's my (incomplete) Deployment file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe
      convert
    kompose.version: 1.14.0 (fa706f2)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:   
      labels:
       io.kompose.service: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: web 
          image: gcr.io/abc/node-node:latest
```

I have a build step which creates an Image and uploads to GCR.

What I want is for Kubernetes to automatically deploy latest image once its uploaded to registry.

I'm missing `imagePullPolicy: "Always"` from my deployment and how to use this command?

`kubectl set image deployment/web web=gcr.io/abc/node-node:latest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto update pod on every image push to GCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751550/auto-update-pod-on-every-image-push-to-gcr)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to yaml file

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/{your_project}/{name}:$$version
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: {name}
```